# Matplotlib Graph Only Has One y-axis Tick Mark? Plotting manually vs Tkinter Button

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, plot, graph

For some reason, my matplotlib isn't adding y-axis tick parts for the whole graph when calling my plotting function with a tkinter button. However, if I just call the plotting function manually, then the y-axis tick marks do show up. The data is being plotted correctly on both graphs. It's just one of them is missing most of the y-axis tick marks.

[image: The graph when calling my plotting function with a tkinter button]

The graph when calling my plotting function with a tkinter button

[image: The graph when calling my plotting function manually with a script]

The graph when calling my plotting function manually with a script

**Note: The graphs may look like they're plotting two different things. They are the same, the scaling is just messed up for some reason.**

This is the function my tkinter button calls. It's just setting some parameters and calling the graph function

```
def plotLightCurve():

    myLCG.setCheckChoice(int(checkStarChoice.get()))
    myLCG.setChoiceMag(check_star_mag_box.get())

    myLCG.ConfigureFile()
    myLCG.process_data()

    myLCG.LCG_Plot()
```

This is the plot function itself

```
def LCG_Plot(self):

    subplot = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

    subplot.scatter(self.jd_list, self.c2_app_mag, label="c2 apparent mag.")
    subplot.scatter(self.jd_list, self.c3_app_mag, label="c3 apparent mag.")
    subplot.scatter(self.jd_list, self.c4_app_mag, label="c4 apparent mag.")

    if self.source_c5_list[0] != 0:
        subplot.scatter(self.jd_list, self.c5_app_mag, label="c5 apparent mag.")
    if self.source_c6_list[0] != 0:
        subplot.scatter(self.jd_list, self.c6_app_mag, label="c6 apparent mag.")

    subplot.scatter(self.jd_list, self.t1_app_mag, label="t1 apparent mag.")

    subplot.legend(title='Object Magnititudes', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0), loc='upper left')
    # subplot.tight_layout()

    plt.scatter(self.jd_list, self.c2_app_mag, label="c2 apparent mag.")
    plt.scatter(self.jd_list, self.c3_app_mag, label="c3 apparent mag.")
    plt.scatter(self.jd_list, self.c4_app_mag, label="c4 apparent mag.")

    plt.show()
```

Here is my script for manually plotting the graph. **Note: The filepath, ChoiceMag, and CheckChoice are set elsewere in the tkinter version.**

```
import LCGLib

myLCG = LCGLib.LCG()

myLCG.setFilePath('Measurements6.csv')
myLCG.setChoiceMag(8.91)
myLCG.setCheckChoice(1)

myLCG.ConfigureFile()
myLCG.process_data()
myLCG.LCG_Plot()
```